# Downloading images from a server

Tags: python, wget

i wanna download images from a server using python but for e.g the URL is "example.com/photo/1.jpg" i wanna run the script again and again but with different image name

here is my code

```
import wget
fileurl = 0
url = 'http://example.com/photo/' + str(fileurl) + '.jpg'

while fileurl != 500:
 fileurl += 1
download = wget.download(url)
```

Comment: You never change `url` and I assume that the download should be part of the loop.

Comment: you could replace your while loop with: `fileurl = 500`. that's probably not what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the url line in the loop, it will change every iteration. In your current code it never changes.

```
import wget
fileurl = 0

while fileurl != 500:
    url = 'http://example.com/photo/' + str(fileurl) + '.jpg'
    fileurl += 1
    try:
        download = wget.download(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: it is giving me a sytem error Traceback (most recent call last): raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: Because the url doesnt exist. If  you change the url to an existing image it wont.

Comment: my bad i forgot to change the url

Comment: hey bro how can i pass a HTTPError 404, for example: on a server only two images exits 1.jpg and 10 .jpg how can i continue it till 10.jpg without stopping on 2.jpg